# Помогите настроить htaccess без лишних запросов на сервер

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте, на сайте реализовано ЧПУ по этому все запросы перенаправляю на index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(jpg|gif|swf|ico)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Затем добавил на сайт SSL сертификат и соответственно нужно было перекидывать с http на https использую вот такой код:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Теперь необходимо избавиться от дублей, убрать в конце слэш , не могу понять как настроить пробывал вот так:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Но работает только с главной страницей https://site.ru
Если переходим в https://site.ru/catalog то уже не работает...
Весь код htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(jpg|gif|swf|ico)$ index.php [NC,L] 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Интересует мнение правильно ли его использую? где можно улучшить код? и как убрать с конца ссылок все слэши дабы не было дубликатов страниц?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для HTTPS использовать следующую конструкцию

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```